# Как предотвратить клонирование?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код который клонирует и пускает в бесконечную карусель изображение из блока:

```js
$(function() {
  $("img").clone().appendTo('.container-logo');
  var $icons = $('.slide-logo');

  function loopImg() {
    var $first = $icons.find('.container-logo img:first-child');
    $first.animate({
      'marginLeft': '-=' + $first.outerWidth(true) + 'px'
    }, 2000, 'linear', function() {
      $first.clone().removeAttr('style').appendTo($first.parent());
      $first.remove();
      loopImg();
    });
  }
  loopImg();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icons slide-logo">
  <div class="container-logo">
    <img src="http://childrenscience.ru/sandbox/roman/sanbox/roman/dialog/img/snowflake.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xh6t16ub/2/

Проблема в том, что при добавлении второго такого блока с другим изображением он копирует изображение из первого блока с помощью `.clone()`
Как можно это предотвратить и сделать так что бы для каждого блока копировалось своё изображение?

Comment: Вы хотите добавить второй блок `.container-logo` или второе изображение в данный блок ?

Comment: Нет.
Нужно что бы при копировании блока Html, изображение внутри этого блока не клонировалось из первого.
Проще говоря если нам нужна вторая такая анимация с другой картинкой, то этого не получается, так как во второй блок, где находится уже другое изображение, клонируется изображение из первого блока.

Вот пример
https://jsfiddle.net/xh6t16ub/3/

во второй блок копируется первое изображение

Comment: казалось бы очевидным, что начать надо с написания цикла?